# Conditions needed for reaction between FeCl3 and KI

Tags: reaction-mechanism

$$\ce{FeCl3 + KI + H2SO4 -> ?}$$

For the reaction to proceed, is it necessary to have the medium acidified, here with sulfuric acid?

Comment: What reaction are you thinking of?

Comment: FeCl3 + KI + H2SO4

Comment: Do you know what the products are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, you can drop $\ce{H2SO4}$ from the equation. However, in practives it is necessary to acidify $\ce{FeCl3}$ water solutions to suppress hydrolysis.

Comment: I have dissolved iron(III) chloride in de-ionized water (pH ~ 7) many times and I have yet to see hydrolysis. I think you mean something else.

Comment: @LDC3 Nope, I mean exactly this. Try to measure the pH of such solution.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only information I found is presented [here](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~rdominey/301/local/iodine_titrations.pdf).

The reaction should be able to proceed in both acidic and neutral solutions. Since iron hydroxides are slightly soluble, the solution is acidified so the hydroxides cannot form.